# how to get the source of the first image by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a simple gallery with 4 images.
I wrote a pice of code but the result is always `undefined`.
What I want is to show by default the first picture in div with class `little`

This is HTML code :

```
<img class="imageToShow" />
<div class="little">
    <img class="imageNotToShow" src="../Images/gallery1.jpg" />
    <img class="imageNotToShow" src="../Images/gallery2.jpg" />
    <img class="imageNotToShow" src="../Images/gallery3.jpg" />
    <img class="imageNotToShow" src="../Images/gallery4.jpg" />
</div>
```

This is the js code :

```
var firstImageSrc;
firstImageSrc = $('.imageNotToShow').first().attr("src");
alert(firstImageSRC);
$('.ImageToShow').attr("src", firstImageSrc);
```

Comment: Try with Id for the image. Class will call all images.

Comment: @TanmoySarkar That's why there's `first()`... as the name suggests, it grabs the first element from the array.

Comment: Is the code wrapped in `ready`? What do you get in `<img class="imageToShow" />`?

Comment: We need more context. If this code is in a script tag at the **end** of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag (e.g., where it should be), it should work fine. (You'll also get people telling you to put it in a `ready` callback, but that's unnecessary if the script tag is in the right place.)

Comment: Almost certainly a duplicate of [*Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Your alert is undefined because you use `firstImageSRC` instead of `firstImageSrc`, your image isn't updated as you use `.ImageToShow` instead of `.imageToShow` - watch your cases, js is case sensitive when it comes to variables names and class selectors

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks brother, I just change the  just before the closing </body> and it works fine for me 
thank you again

Comment: If you want to lazy load the images (currently they're all loaded at once), you could use HTML like `<span class="imageNotToShow" data-src="../Images/gallery1.jpg"></span>` then use `$(".imageNotToShow").first().data("src");` to get the 1st URL

Answer (score 1):

Jquery selectors are case sensitive so correct your class selector 
ImageToShow to imageToShow...

```js
var firstImageSrc = $('.imageNotToShow').first().attr("src");
$('.imageToShow').attr("src", firstImageSrc);
```

```css
.imageNotToShow{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="imageToShow" />
<div class="little">
    <img class="imageNotToShow" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x151" />
    <img class="imageNotToShow" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x152" />
    <img class="imageNotToShow" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x153" />
    <img class="imageNotToShow" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x154" />
</div>
```

Comment: i changed the selector after i posted the question, $('.imageNotToShow').first().attr("src") = 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

> $('.ImageToShow').attr("src", firstImageSrc);

Your CSS selector in jQuery code is not matching. Change `ImageToShow` to `imageToShow` and things will work fine.

Comment: your'e alright but this is not the reason why i got 'undifend'

Comment: That was not your question either.

Comment: read the question again